# Change the type in a Python list?

Tags: python, list

Is there a Pythonic way to change the type of every object in a list?

For example, I have a list of objects `Queries`.
Is there a fancy way to change that list to a list of strings?

e.g.

```
lst = [<Queries: abc>, <Queries: def>]
```

would be changed to

```
lst = ['abc', 'def']
```

When `str()` is used on a `Queries` object, the strings I get are the ones in the second code sample above, which is what I would like.

Or do I just have to loop through the list?

Many thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 11):

```
newlst = [str(x) for x in lst]
```

You could use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
new_list = map(str, lst)
```

Comment: Dogbert, thank you very much. I didn't realise it was that simple. I'll accept this as my answer when I am allowed to! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this (Python 3):

```
new_list = list(map(str, lst))
```

or

```
new_list = [str(q) for q in lst]
```